# Modify docstring in a decorator

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I am using flask, and some functions have decorators, to check the presence of some headers and return some error codes if they are missing.

In these decorators, before returning the decorated function i do something like

```
decorated_function.__doc__ += "Returns 400 if the X-Version header is not present."
```

Is this pythonic? Is there a better way to achieve it?

I am using wraps already from functools.

Comment: To have the docstring of the function indicate both what the function is doing and what the decorator is doing.

Comment: "Pythonic" is one of those words that everything seems to know the definition to, but in many cases is subjective. I don't think there is a good enough definition of it to definitely say if the code same you have is actually pythonic. That being said, I don't think it is a good idea. A docstring might have specific markup or design that your function may not recognize. Therefore, I would suggest not doing this. However, if it works and isn't confusing for you, then by all means feel free to.

Answer (score 3):

```
def ModDoc(doc):
    def wrapped(func):
        func.__doc__ = doc
        return func
    return wrapped


@ModDoc("test2")
def test():
    """test"""
    return

print test.__doc__
```

Will modify the docstring of anything it is applied too. Remember these changes are purely interactive, and will not show up in stored or auto generated documentation.

Comment: That's wraps from functools, Am using it already.